# How to create "schemes" with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose, composable

In my Android Studio app projects [I registered all activities, services, receivers etc. in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters). I also could define schemes like:

```
myApp://MyMapActivity/x_and_y_coordinates
```

to open my app with this certain designated Activity and prefilles map area for instance. So I could either start this Activity from other apps or I could create notifications to start these Activities accordingly.

Now, I am creating an Android app with jetpack compose, I have one single Activity in which I compose all "views".. How would I be able to go to the map view immediately via jetpack compose?

Comment: The Jetpack Navigation component handles deep links. Once Navigation supports Compose, then you should be able to set up your deep links to map to composables. In the interim, you would have your activity handle the deep links and update some state that causes your UI to recompose to the new screen.

Comment: @CommonsWare Where do you know that? Are there any articles so I can dig in?

Comment: "Where do you know that?" -- where do I know *what*? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking covers Android's support for deep links in general. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link covers the Navigation component's support for deep links within the app. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161472731 chronicles the upcoming Navigation support for composables. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state covers state management with Compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to configure you Activity to receive all intents and use the data provided in it to direct your compose tree to show the view you want.